# Why my console says data-Id is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a marker, I have a checkbox which should pass a value form `locations[i][3]` to `map-checked-box`

```
    locations[i][3] = 123;
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + locations[i][3] + " 
<input type='checkbox' class='map-checked-box mr-1' data-id='"+ locations[i][3] +"' >`");`
```

here it should receive value

```
     $("body").delegate('.map-checked-box', "click", function(){
          var dataID = $(this).data('id');
          console.log(dataId);
}
```

but it says dataId is not defined.

This is the button target model

```
<button class="show_all_point" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-modal-points">Show All Points</button>
```

**either it should solve or suggest me any other method which pass `location[1][3]` value to `dataId` on click checkbox**

Comment: `let locations[i][3] = 123;` is a syntax error. Also you set `dataID` but console.log `dataId`. Also (unrelated but) `.delegate()` has been deprecated for almost 10 years.

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive.  `dataID` != `dataId`.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `delegate()` has been deprecated for many years

Comment: #Guy Incognito this is just let locations[i][3] considering value i have array where location = [ "name " , 123,456 , 987] and here i splited all values by "," and then 987 passes to  locations[i][3]

Comment: marc you are right now i noticed that dataID != dataId i was passing wrong variable thanx for helped its resolved

Comment: `let` is to defined a variable in a scope. You have already the variable `locations` which is an array. to update their values you dont need `let`, `var` or `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataID != dataId so i pass it and worked

```
$("body").delegate('.map-checked-box', "click", function(){
          var dataID = $(this).data('id');
          console.log(dataID);
}
```